# Cassandra and apache spark db design to achieve datewise filter

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, spark-streaming

In my application all realtime data storing in a cassandra table, I have plan to analyze it using apache spark and put it into different tables which allows faster data fetch, I want to know which design approach I need to apply for it.

Analyze relatime table in a time-frame , then put in to hourly , then analyze later make it to daily , then weekly etc..., Then it is easy to achieve data in a date range. Is my logic is fine or any other approach with cassandra and spark?

Comment: Without knowing what your requirements are, it's very difficult to suggest any solution. There're many different alternatives that could do the same job.

Comment: @maasg My purpose is collect data from client application and it will store in cassandra without modification. I will call it as realtime data , we can expect 100s of records per second. Need to display in dash board, need to filter, Need to show with different date range, need to change status, Need to mute archive etc.., It is helpful if you can suggest all the alternatives, I will check it.

Comment: They do something similar here: https://github.com/killrweather/killrweather it would be better if you have more specific questions. Design suggestions are mostly opinion and actually off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It is very helpful for me, Please put it or like projects as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is good.It is similar to **Lambda Architecture** designed by Nathan Marz. For more information, follow this [link](http://lambda-architecture.net/) .Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how a simple roll-up calculation relates to the lambda architecture.